# Prevent a system service from starting of another specified unit is active

Tags: systemd

I have two daemons that are both configured as `systemd` services. Both are launched by timer units. Is there a way for one service to be configure not to run if the other is active?

One is a processing daemon that does database builds in near real-time (runs every 15 minutes). The other is a maintenance and cleanup task that runs daily. If the build daemon is running I don't want the maintenance daemon to run at all.

Comment: Could you instead launch one thing that would once per day do the maintenance and then either abort or do the regular tasks?